# show the equivalences without using truth table

Tags: logic

**I)**
$(p→q)⇔(p→p∧q)≡T$

**II)**
$(p→q)⇔(p∨q→q)≡T$

**III)**
$(p→q)⇔(p∧~q→c)≡T$

my try:

about the first one we have:
$$(p→q)⇔(p→p∧q)≡T$$
$$((p→q)⇒(p→p∧q))∧((p→p∧q)⇒(p→q))$$
⇒)$$(p→q)→(p→p∧q)≡(p→q)→(\sim p∨p∧q)$$$$≡
(p→q)→(T∧q)≡(p→q)→(q)≡
\sim (\sim p∨q)∨(q)$$$$≡(p∧\sim q)∨(q)≡p∧(\sim q∨q)≡p∧T≡p$$
about the others I have similar problem.

Comment: Hint for the first one : use [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) to rewrite $p \to q$ as $\lnot p \lor q$ and apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to the RHS

Comment: Similar for the second one.

Comment: how I can use distributivity ? I don't get your hint

Comment: What about natural deduction?  For the first task to prove $\Leftarrow$, it's given that $p\rightarrow p\land q$.  Now assume $p\land\lnot q$, from which both $p$ and $\lnot q$ may be concluded.  But from $p$ we have $p\land q$, especially $q$, so we conclude $q\land\lnot q$, hence our assumption was false.

Comment: I've linked the Wiki's entry about Distributivity with the equivalences to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence):

\begin{align}
&(p→p∧q)\tag{1}\\
&\equiv\neg p\lor (p\land q)\tag*{conditional equivalence}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor p)\land(\neg p\lor q)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv\top\land(\neg p\lor q)\tag*{Negation law}\\
&\equiv\neg p\lor q\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\equiv p\to q\tag*{conditional equivalence}\\
&\\
&(p∨q→q)\tag{2}\\
&\equiv\neg(p∨q)\lor q\tag*{conditional equivalence}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\land \neg q)\lor q\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor q)\land(\neg q\lor q)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor q)\land\top\tag*{Negation law}\\
&\equiv\neg p \lor q\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\equiv p\to q\tag*{conditional equivalence}\\
&\\
&\tag{3}\\
&\text{take $p\equiv q\equiv\top,c\equiv\bot$}\tag*{counter example}\\
&p∧ q→c\equiv\top\land\top\to\bot\equiv\top\to\bot\equiv\bot\\
&p\to q\equiv \top\to\top\equiv\top\\
&\bot\not\equiv\top\tag*{Not True}\\
\end{align}